Vim-latex with Neovim
I recently moved from working in Vim to Neovim. One thing that has changed while using vim-latex is the ability to automatically insert an \item tag inside an itemize/enumerate environment. When working in Vim this could be achieved by pressing either <Tab> or <C-i> while the cursor (in insert mode) was inside an itemize/enumerate environment. In Neovim though this no longer behaves the same, it just produces a tab whitespace, for both <Tab> and <C-i>. I assume this is something to do with the internal keymaps for Neovim but I have not been able to find a solution. Has anyone come across this before? Does anyone have any suggestions of where I could look for a solution?
EDIT: I have done some more searching and seem to have forgotten than I defined some additional keymaps in a tex.vim file that is located in ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-latex/ftplugin/. In tex.vim I have the following keymaps
map <C-e> <f5>
imap <C-e> <f5>
imap <C-l> <Plug>Tex_LeftRight
imap <C-i> <Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine
map <leader>k :w<CR><bar><leader>ll<leader>ls

While in a TeX file all these maps work except the <C-i> mapping. I have checked while in a TeX file (on both Vim and Neovim) and :imap <C-i> returns i <C-I> <Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine.

What do :map <Tab> and :map <C-I> say? Do they point to the right thing?

@Friedrich <Tab> is mapped to some things for UltiSnips in x and s mode and <C-I> is mapped to <C-Y> in all modes. This is consistent between my installation of Vim and Neovim.

I can't reproduce your problem :-| Are you sure vim-latex is correctly installed?

Could you tell us what is the result of the following command: imap <Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine?

@VivianDeSmedt that returns i <Plug> <Nop> and i <Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine & <C-R>=Tex_InsertItem()<CR>

What if in insert mode you hit: <C-r>=Tex_InsertItem()<Cr> where <C-r> stand for Ctrl-r and <Cr> stands for Enter?

@VivianDeSmedt <C-r> enters some kind of weird input mode where typing = starts entering into the command line so effectively <C-r>=Tex_InsertItem()<CR> is equivalent to running the command =Tex_InsertItem() which of course inserts and \item tag.

Thanks for the feedback. I don't understand why it is not working at your end :-|

@VivianDeSmedt You and me both! Thanks for trying to help :)
